# Peterson's algorithm and deadlock

Tags: multithreading, go, multiprocessing, deadlock

I am trying to experiment with some mutual execution algorithms. I have implemented the Peterson's algorithm. It prints the correct counter value but sometimes it seems just like some kind of a deadlock had occurred which stalls the execution indefinitely. This should not be possible since this algorithm is deadlock free.

PS: Is this related to problems with compiler optimizations often mentioned when addressing the danger of "benign" data races? If this is the case then how to disable such optimizations?

PPS: When atomically storing/loading the victim field, the problem seems to disappear which makes the compiler's optimizations more suspicious

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type mutex struct {
    flag   [2]bool
    victim int
}

func (m *mutex) lock(id int) {
    m.flag[id] = true // I'm interested
    m.victim = id     // you can go before me if you want
    for m.flag[1-id] && m.victim == id {
        // while the other thread is inside the CS
        // and the victime was me (I expressed my interest after the other one already did)
    }
}

func (m *mutex) unlock(id int) {
    m.flag[id] = false // I'm not intersted anymore
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var mu mutex
    var cpt, n = 0, 100000

    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(id int) {
            defer wg.Done()

            for j := 0; j < n; j++ {
                mu.lock(id)
                cpt = cpt + 1
                mu.unlock(id)
            }
        }(i)
    }

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(cpt)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "benign" data race. Your program has data race, and the behavior is undefined.

At the core of the problem is the `mutex` implementation. Modifications made to a shared object from one goroutine are not necessarily observable from others until those goroutines communicate using one of the synchronization primitives. You are writing to `mutex.victim` from multiple goroutines, and won't be observed. You are also reading the `mutex.flag` elements written by other goroutines, and won't necessarily be seen. That is, there may be cases where the for-loop won't terminate even if the other goroutine changes the variables.

And since the mutex implementation is broken, the updates to `cpt` will not necessarily be correct either.

To implement this correctly, you need the `sync/atomic` package.

See the Go Memory Model: https://go.dev/ref/mem

Comment: Yep! This should be some kind of undefined behavior. Thanks!

Comment: There are benign data races but you need to know what you are doing. The String hash optimization in Java is a good example of a benign data race.

Comment: @pveentjer, do you have any links explaining that?

Comment: For the String.hash optimization you can check the code. Since the outcome of the optimized code is the same as when the hash field would be volatile, the optimization is allowed (hence benign). Also, keep in mind that acquire/release and opaque in Java officially are data races since they are not synchronization operations.

Comment: Nitpick mode: When there is a data-race in Go, the behavior is still defined: a read either needs to see a write ordered by the happens-before or it needs to be concurrent.  See Requirement 3 in https://go.dev/ref/mem. In Java, this is called happens-before consistent. In C++, for example, allows for any value to be seen, and therefore the behavior is truly undefined.

Answer (score 0):

For Peterson's algorithm (same goes for Dekker), you need to ensure that your code is sequential consistent. In Go you can do that using atomics. This will prevent the compiler and the hardware to mess things up.